# Maven build fails on Bluemix dev ops pipeline but passes locally

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I am receiving the following error for an app being build on Bluemix using the devops pipeline. The build command is

```
mvn -B package
```

and the same command works without a problem on my local server.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compilerplugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project api: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

[My build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm7dA.png)

Am I missing a configuration step in my pipeline? Why the delta?

Two nice features: I want to name the custom stages. If you delete the red/green stage I want to create a new one as a template.

Answer (score 0):

In your build script try setting JAVA_HOME to Java8 and adding it to the path.  Java7 is there by default.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA8_HOME
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Adding this made the build pass! Thank you for your quick reply. Is there a way to add this into the image, I imagine we're using docker under the covers, so that a user does not have to manually add the java home? Also, what did you think about my feedback on future products?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set in the image.  Just to Java 7 by default.